# parsley.js catching all errors and outputting via a javascript alert()

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I want to catch all errors on a form using pasley v2.8 in a single event and then display those errors via a standard javascript alert.

I had this working in part before thanks to assistance in this SO [question about the fieldinstance functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120734/parsley-js-get-an-error-list-using-callback/24756674?noredirect=1#comment83807432_24756674).   However the code in that other question works with a function being called as every form element fails.

What I want is an event that fires just once after all the errors have been collated.   I believe this is done via the recent form:error event.  The code I've made isn't working due to getErrorsMessages() seeming to not function.   What I have so far is...

```
$('#form').parsley().on('form:error', function (formInstance) {
    var errorMsg = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(formInstance);
    alert(errorMsg);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `formInstance` to loop through each field and retrieve the error messages. Like this

```
<form class="demo-form">
    <input type="text" name="field1" required />
    <input type="text" name="field2" required />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('.demo-form').parsley().on('form:error', function (formInstance) {
        var errors = [];

        // You have access to each field instance with `formInstance.fields`
        for (var idx in formInstance.fields) {
            errors.push((formInstance.fields[idx].getErrorsMessages()));

            // Use $element to access the jQuery element of each field
            console.log(formInstance.fields[idx].$element);
        }

        alert(errors);
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want to remove the messages next to each field that are displayed automatically by Parsley, you can add the following attribute to your form: `data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42858521/908174).

Comment: Thanks so much!  Just to check, accessing the input field names, do you know how that is done ?  Currently I just get the error messages but this doesnt include the field names.

Comment: @AdamJones Check the updated answer. `formInstance.fields[id]` will return the `fieldInstance` of Parsley. That object has a `$element` property which is the jQuery element. So you can access any DOM attributes with `formInstance.fields[0].$element.attr('name')`